# Extending a triangulation from a manifold boundary to the interior

Tags: triangulation, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a (second-countable topological) compact connected manifold-with-boundary. Suppose $\partial M$ has a triangulation. Does there exist a triangulation of $M$ which extends the triangulation on $\partial M$? If not, what additional conditions would be required for this to hold?

For background, I would like to extend the result that this is true when $M$ is the closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here the triangulation is extended by adding simplex-cones from the center of the ball to the boundary-simplices.

Comment: No: For instance take the E8 manifold and remove an open ball from it.

Comment: Thanks, should have thought that myself. I wonder if it suffices to require $M$ triangulable?

Comment: I am sure it is false as well.